# right click menus, dropdown menus have no shadows and borders

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, menu, 15.04

I installed kubuntu-desktop on existing unity installation but for some bugs disliked it and removed it. Now there is this problem, windows in unity have shadows and borders, but the right click and panel menus don't have shadows and borders, i reset compiz unity, reinstalled ubuntu-desktop, unity, compiz but the problem is still here. I tried to take screenshots but screenshot shortcuts does not work when you have right click menu open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so kde changed some files and they were the culprits. Deleting

> ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini

brought back the menu shadows/borders.

Comment: not working for me. i followed your idea and logged out and logged in again